# Connecting a create-react-app with server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, create-react-app

I have a react application (using create-react-app) and I have made the front end and back end part separately, but I am having trouble connecting my express server with the front end.  As of right now, I have a server folder within my react application that is running on its own from the front end.  This is how I have started connecting the front end to the server in `app.js`

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));

app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
});
```

When I view the application, I have to start the server first from a terminal window, then from a separate terminal window I start the react application.  How would I connect the front and backend of the application so that the express server serves the react app.  [image: file structure of my project]

I have looked through many posts online and videos but cannot find a clear answer to how I can do this.

Comment: `yarn start` will start webpack dev server that you use during development, when you want to run your code on a web server you use `yarn build` and host the build files on your webserver. When you want to use an api in your react app you can set up a [proxy](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/) during development.

Comment: Do you need just publish your react app in a nodejs server?

Comment: @JRichardsz I am trying to connect the front end to the back end, since I only have the front end and back end separate and running on different ports.  My goal is to deploy the all as a single page application.  Possibly using heroku or firebase

Comment: If you need to deploy your react code in heroku, you need a **simple server** + result of your npm run build on react code. Is this **simple server** your nodejs backend or your nodejs backend has another functionalities like rest endpoints?

Comment: @JRichardsz my node backend has a mongo db as well as handling server routes.  I am inexperienced when it comes to web development, and do not know what rest endpoints are.

Comment: How is the data exchange between your react and nodejs-mongo app? Are you are using axios in react to send and receive data from/to your nodejs (static server + mongo) ? SPA is not all (react js + backend nodejs) in one . Is just a js app running as one bundle in the browser instead of html server renderization like other old frameworks.

Comment: @JRichardsz yes, I am using axios to make calls to the server from the front end.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214451/discussion-between-jrichardsz-and-stuart-fong).